# Okay to delete SQLServer2005 security groups?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server, windows-server-2016

Our office has three servers running WS2016 Standard, we upgraded from SBS 2011 a couple years ago. Some things still exist from that time. I don't think the following security groups are related to the SBS install, but I'm not certain. They do not have any members and are not members of any other groups. We do run a couple SQL servers, but I don't think they are SQL 2005 either.

I'm fairly confident that these are safe to delete, but I am not very well versed in SQL so I wanted to be sure. Server beginning with WIN- was a failed install and no longer exists.

[ADUC Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h523c.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled Active Directory Recycle Bin in Active Directory Administrative Center (ADAC)? If you delete these groups with AD Recycle Bin enabled, you'll be able to restore them (and any other AD object) by navigating to the Deleted Objects container in ADAC.